# lvalue required as unary '&" operand

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

I have a problem with my project which is supposed to add up every line using a thread then sum it all, but I'm getting an error that says lvalue required as unary '&" operand

pthread_create(&tid, NULL, &sum_line(0), NULL);

I've tried some thing but couldn't solve it, any ideas? Thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
static void * sum_line(int nr_line);

int Sum;
int A[4][4];

int main() {
  pthread_t tid;
  Sum=0;
  printf("\nOrig thread tid(%d) Sum=%d", pthread_self(), Sum);
  pthread_create(&tid, NULL, &sum_line(0), NULL);
  printf("\nChild thread was created tid(%d)", tid);
  pthread_join(tid,NULL);
  printf("\nOrig thread tid(%d)-->Child thread ended tid(%d) Sum=%d",pthread_self(), tid, Sum);
  printf("\n");

}

static void * sum_line(int nr_line) {
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<4;i++) {
        Sum=Sum+A[i];
        printf("\nChild thread tid(%d), i=%d, Sum=%d",pthread_self(),i,Sum);
        sleep(2);
    }
    printf("\nChild thread tid(%d)--> ending", pthread_self());
}
```

Comment: `&sum_line(0)` - what is this supposed to give?

Comment: `void * sum_line()` is missing `return` statements.

Comment: `pthread_create(&tid, NULL, sum_line, (void*)0)`, this will cause sum_line to be called, the next argument will be the first argument to the same function. Probably best to declare your `int nr_line` argument as `void*` as well and then cast it to the value.

Answer (score 2):

#### Pass a pointer to function to `pthread_create()`

Write just `sum_line`, not `&sum_line(0)`.

The `pthread_create()` function expects a pointer to the thread function — i.e. the function name — and not the result of calling the function.  The `pthread_create()` function will arrange for the new thread to call the function, but it needs a function pointer.

Also, the signature for a thread function must be:

```
void *function(void *arg);
```

The function should also return a value — add `return 0;` before the close brace.

You pass a null pointer to the function; you can't expect that to work as `int nr_line`.  You'll need to do some fancy footwork to get a number to the function.
There are two main options:

#### Either

```
int nr_line = 247;

pthread_create(&tid, NULL, sum_line, &nr_line);
```

The function then looks like:

```
void *sum_line(void *arg)
{
    int nr_line = *(int *)arg;
    …
    return 0;
}
```

Just make sure each thread gets a pointer to a different object when you start multiple threads.

#### Or

```
uintptr_t nr_line = 247;
pthread_create(&tid, NULL, sum_line, (void *)nr_line);
```

Or:

```
int nr_line = 247;
pthread_create(&tid, NULL, sum_line, (void *)(uintptr_t)nr_line);
```

and the function then looks like:

```
void *sum_line(void *arg)
{
    int nr_line = (uintptr_t)arg;
    …
    return 0;
}
```

The double cast avoids compiler warnings about converting an integer of a different size to a pointer.

Note that `pthread_create()` will call the function as if it is `void *function(void *args)`, so passing it any other type of function pointer, even if cast with `(void (*)(void *))`, is cheating and leads to undefined behaviour.

Comment: better to allocate the arg to give and free it in sum_line, to not cast _int_ to _void *_ and reverse (oupps in 64b) nor to take the risk the local var disappear (here protected by the join). Just my 2 cents ;-)

Comment: @bruno — there are many ways to deal with it.  What I've outlined are two acceptable ways (IMO), and I noted that it is important to make sure that multiple threads each get a separate argument.  Allocation is another option; it isn't s necessary one.  It would be feasible to have a local variable that's an array of a suitable type and pass a pointer to a different element of the array to each thread, for example.  Of course you have to make sure that the lifetimes of variables are properly respected — that's always the case.  If you allocate, you also have to free.  It's not necessary here.

Comment: I just hope for ton to understand all of that, lot of people copy/paste code without checking if the full context is the same, I certainly do not learn you that ^^ To propose a robust code for the same price (a couple of malloc & free is nothing) limits the possible future problems

Comment: Since I wouldn't use `malloc()` and `free()` myself, usually — but it depends on context — I won't recommend it.  I do accept it is perfectly possible.  Starting a single thread is unusual — it demonstrates 'training exercise', especially when the thread function has `sleep(2);` in the middle of its loop.  The suggested changes will get the training exercise to work.